# Apache spark Row getAs[String] : java.lang.Byte cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark Dataframe, which looks like this:

```
+-----------+-----+
|foo        |  bar|
+-----------+-----+
|          3|10119|
|          2| 4305|
+-----------+-----+
```

And it has the following schema

```scala
org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(
    StructField(foo,ByteType,true), 
    StructField(bar,LongType,false)
)
```

As you can see, the column `foo` is of `ByteType`.

I need to get the first row of `foo` as a String.

When I try

```scala
val fooStr = df.first.getAs[String](0)
```

I get cast exception :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Byte cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

However when I use `toString`, I am able to cast

```scala
val myStr = df.first.get(0).toString
```

Why is it that when I use `Row.getAs[String]` I get a casting exception , but when I use `toString`, there is no error. Is there any drawback to using `toString`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Row.getAs[T](i)` is [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/2d6232aac476e8afe323fd56d461fadaf2550bb1/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.scala#L356) defined as

```scala
def getAs[T](i: Int): T = get(i).asInstanceOf[T]
```

`asInstanceOf[T]` simply tries to cast the object to the desired type (see [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/Any.html#asInstanceOf%5BT0%5D:T0)) without any further transformations. If the type returned by `get(i)` and the desired type are not compatible (like Byte and String) a ClassCastException is thrown.

Calling `toString` on the return value of `get(0)` means however that [Byte.toString()](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Byte.html#toString():String) is called. This is not a cast but a regular method call that returns a String.